# Spring-integration-ftp streaming files from ftp delete files from server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am working on a Spring Boot App to read files from a FTP server and write the data into database. I am using Spring Integration FTP with streaming (FtpStreamingMessageSource)

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "streamPHI", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "2000", maxMessagesPerPoll="-1"))
public MessageSource<InputStream> ftpMessageSourcePHI() {
    FtpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new FtpStreamingMessageSource(templatePhi, null);
    messageSource.setRemoteDirectory(remoteDirectory);
    messageSource.setFilter(new FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "streaming"));
    return messageSource;
}
```

This is turn stream this into another channel

```
@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel = "streamPHI", outputChannel = "data")
public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer transformerPhi() {
    return new StreamTransformer();
}
```

When the polling starts, it successfully gets the files, but also DELETES the files from remote FTP server. which is not required. Can anyone suggest what might be the cause ?

Thanks

---- Update

But in my case, I have not written anything to delete the file. After the first "Transformation" I have used another transformation that will just get me the content of the file from byte to string. And, then a service activator to parse and save it into database.

```
@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel = "data", outputChannel = "parse-shipping")
public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer handler() {
    return new ByteToStringTransformer();

}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "parse-shipping")
public void parseShippingInformation(String shipFileContent){
...
}


@Component
public class ByteToStringTransformer extends AbstractTransformer {

@Override
protected Object doTransform(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
    byte[] x = (byte[]) message.getPayload();
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : x) {
        str.append((char) b);
    }
    str.append(message.getHeaders().get("file_remoteFile"));
    return str.toString();
}
```

}

Is there anything on FTP Settings that might be causing this? (Same time I am also looking into this but any hints will be helpful)

Comment: do you have any config (.xml) files around this that you can show?

Comment: No, there is no XML configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the adapter that will delete the file; in fact the documentation mentions that...

> Unlike the non-streaming inbound channel adapter, this adapter does not prevent duplicates by default. If you do not delete the remote file (e.g. using an outbound gateway with an `rm` command) and you wish to prevent the file being processed again, you can configure an FtpPersistentFileListFilter in the filter attribute. If you don’t actually want to persist the state, an in-memory SimpleMetadataStore can be used with the filter. If you wish to use a filename pattern (or regex) as well, use a CompositeFileListFilter.

Something else must be deleting your file.

Comment: Thank you Gary. But I have not written anything that will delete the files but somehow it is getting deleted.. Please see my edited post if you can find out anything. I have tested the same in local FTP server which did not delete any file, but when added for production FTP, it did so.

Comment: Must be the server then. A network trace of the ftp protocol will prove it.